# GoLang pointers are behaving wierd

Tags: go, pointers, linked-list

Why does changing node2.Next affects node2 in the below code?

```
import "fmt"

type ListNode struct {
    Val int
    Next *ListNode
}


func main() {
    node1 := ListNode{Val:10 , Next:nil}
    node2 := ListNode{Val:100 , Next:&node1}
    temp := node2

    if(temp == node2){
        fmt.Println("Equalssss1")
    }
    node2.Next = &(ListNode{1 , nil})
    if(temp == node2){
        fmt.Println("Equalssss2")
    }
}
```

Basically why doesn't "Equalssss2" doesn't get printed? I feel since node2.Next is changed but not node2, node2 should be equal to temp Why isn't it the case?

Comment: `node2.Next`  is a field in `node2`, so you modified `node2` and it is no longer equal.

Comment: `node2.Next` is part of `node2`, changing it changes `node2`

Comment: The pointers aren't doing anything weird, they're not doing anything at all. You'd see the same thing if you changed `node2.Val`.

Answer (score 2):

There are no misbehaving pointers in your code.  I suspect that what you think are pointers are not actually pointers, hence your confusion.

In your code `node1` and `node2` are `ListNode` structs, i.e. _*value types*.  When you assign `node2` to `temp`, `temp` then holds a *copy* of `node2`, **not** a pointer or reference to it.

In Go, (in simple terms) two struct values are equal if they of the same type and consist of comparable fields that all evaluate as equal.

When you initially compare `node2` and `temp` the values of all of the fields in each of the two values are the same, therefore `temp == node2` evaluates true.

You then change the `Next` field of `node2`, therefore when you again compare `temp == node2` they are no longer equal since they differ in the value of that field.

To get the behaviour you are expecting, `node1` and `node2` would need to be *pointers* to a `ListNode`:

```golang
type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}

func main() {
    node1 := &ListNode{Val: 10, Next: nil}
    node2 := &ListNode{Val: 100, Next: node1}
    temp := node2

    if temp == node2 {
        fmt.Println("Equalssss1")
    }

    node2.Next = &(ListNode{1, nil})
    if temp == node2 {
        fmt.Println("Equalssss2")
    }
}
```

`temp` is now also a pointer to a `ListNode`, rather than a copy of the `ListNode` value; `temp` is initialised to reference the same `ListNode` that `node2` references.  That is, the pointers `temp` and `node2` are equal; they both point to the same `ListNode`.

Now, when you change `node2.Next`, this doesn't affect the fact that `temp` is still just a copy of the `node2` *pointer* and since neither the value of `node2` itself (the pointer) nor `temp` have changed, they are still equal.

i.e. if you were using pointers, your code would behave as expected.  If you think that pointers are behaving "weirdly" it is because, in this instance, you are not actually using pointers. :)

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed explanation, I was using Java for a very long time and so was the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters on your question are trying to point out, nothing at all weird is happening here.  Add this after your first conditional:

```
fmt.Printf("temp is at %p and temp.Next is at %p\nnode2 is at %p and node2.Next is at %p\n", &temp, temp.Next, &node2, node2.Next)
```

this will output:

```
temp is at 0xc00009e240 and temp.Next is at 0xc00009e220
node2 is at 0xc00009e230 and node2.Next is at 0xc00009e220
```

and try adding this line after your second conditional:

```
fmt.Printf("temp.Next has Val: %d\nnode2.Next has Val: %d\n", temp.Next.Val, node2.Next.Val)
```

which will output:

```
temp.Next has Val: 10
node2.Next has Val: 1
```

You can see the result [here](https://go.dev/play/p/HnZ9oXTRFSM).

`node2` and `temp` point to different objects, both of which have the same field values until you modify `node.Next`.  Your assignment `temp := node2` makes creates a new instance of the struct type and copies in the values from the source object.  It does not create a pointer to the `node` object - if it had, then changing `node2.<field>` would also change `temp.<field>`.  This is made slightly confusing by the fact that, in go (unlike in say C) you do not need to dereference the pointer/use different accessor syntax to access struct fields, so the following would be completely fine:

```
temp := &node2
node2.Val = 500
fmt.Printf("%d == %d\n, temp.Val, node2.Val)
```

In the end, everything here is happening exactly as one would expect.  Put another way, your first conditional is checking equality but not identity.  Different objects (identity) with the same values (equality).

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail, I was using Java for a very long time and so was the confusion.